# How to convert the Mapbox js function into Mapbox gl js

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am shifting from the mapbox js to mapbox gl js. I need to convert the leaflet function for the mapbox gl js.

in mapbox.js I was using:

```
imageUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/tiles/{z}/{x}/{myY}.png
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {
        infoControl: false,
        attributionControl: false,
        maxZoom: 21,
        minZoom: 16
    })     
    var TopoLayer = L.tileLayer(imageUrl, {
        maxZoom: 21,
        minZoom: 16,
        myY: function (data) {
            return (Math.pow(2, data.z) - data.y - 1)
      }
    })
```

I am using the 3rd party tiles to overlay on the maps. which was working fine in the leaflet mapbox js. 
How can I change this into mapbox gl js?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What difficulty are you running into when writing the Mapbox-GL-JS code?

Comment: @ Steve Bennett  I am using the zxy folder pattern on the server to overlay the tiles(Geo tagged Arial images taken by drone). 'z ' and  'x' are accurate but 'y' isn't matching to the mapbox calculations so i need to convert the y to my calculations. I cannot find the proper way to do that.

Comment: Try the transformRequest option https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/5021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the OGC TMS spec? You can use `"scheme": "tms"` see https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-raster-scheme

Comment: I am using the zxy directory pattern on the server. Would it work with the tms scheme???

Comment: Yes, the only difference is the meaning of the y.